# Symfony 2 ServiceNotFoundException

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, namespaces

I am trying to use doctrine in my symfony API project, I have this controller but when it is called I get the error "ServiceNotFoundException"

```
<?php

namespace Cogc\EnquirerAPIBundle\Controller;

use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\FOSRestController;
use Doctrine;

class PageController extends FOSRestController
{
    public function getPageAction($id)
    {
        return $this->container->get('doctrine.entity_manager')->getRepository('Page')->find($id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possibly a typo.

Check if the service exist by dumping your container service deifinition via command line as:

```
 php app/console container:debug
```

In my case the service is named as `doctrine.orm.entity_manager`